# removing trailing commas from a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I am creating comma seperated list in PHP, however I can not work out how to remove trailing commas from a string - for examples I may generate a list that looks like this,

> RefundApplicationForm_(1)7.pdf,Mackintosh_-*Shaker*-_Suite_1514.pdf,,,,

I have tried,

`str_replace($list, ",", "");`

but that removes all the commas I only want to remove the last comma and any commas that have no value between them.

I am making the list by doing the following,

`$list .= $value.",";`

Comment: By the way, found the above post by: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+removing+trailing+commas+from+a+string

Comment: See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
$list = rtrim($list, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$list = substr($str, 0, -1);`
personally I prefer the other way around: start with a comma and remove it with a
`$list = substr($str, 1);`